# Jenkins WebSphere deployer plugin fails

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, websphere-8

I am doing a POC and trying to deploy an EAR into WebSphere using the Jenkins WebSphere deployer plugin. WebSphere has security enabled. I tried to import the certificates using InstallCert.java into a cacerts file and use the same. Still no luck.

I'm a newbie and any helps is welcomed. Kindly let me know even the basic step if necessary :)

[image: This is the screenshot of configuration. I have configured the right port number. I have copied the dummy jks files into the security directory from websphere]

This is the exception I face

```
    Connection failed: com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.ConnectorException: ADMC0016E: The system cannot create a SOAP connector to connect to host JHRPSTEST4 at port 8879.
at com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClientFactory.createAdminClientPrivileged(AdminClientFactory.java:634)
at com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClientFactory.access$000(AdminClientFactory.java:126)
at com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClientFactory$1.run(AdminClientFactory.java:209)
at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:63)
at com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClientFactory.createAdminClient(AdminClientFactory.java:205)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.websphere.services.deployment.WebSphereDeploymentService.connect(WebSphereDeploymentService.java:234)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.websphere_deployer.WebSphereDeployerPlugin$DescriptorImpl.doTestConnection(WebSphereDeployerPlugin.java:325)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:298)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:161)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:96)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:120)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:728)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:858)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:248)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:728)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:858)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:248)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:728)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:858)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:631)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:225)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:686)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1494)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:96)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:88)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:48)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:164)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:46)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1474)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:533)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:960)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1021)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClientFactory.createAdminClientPrivileged(AdminClientFactory.java:456)
... 66 more
Caused by: com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.ConnectorNotAvailableException: [SOAPException: faultCode=SOAP-ENV:Client; msg=Error opening socket: java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext); targetException=java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error opening socket: java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)]
at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.reconnect(SOAPConnectorClient.java:422)
at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.<init>(SOAPConnectorClient.java:222)
... 71 more
Caused by: [SOAPException: faultCode=SOAP-ENV:Client; msg=Error opening socket: java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext); targetException=java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error opening socket: java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)]
at org.apache.soap.transport.http.SOAPHTTPConnection.send(SOAPHTTPConnection.java:475)
at org.apache.soap.rpc.Call.WASinvoke(Call.java:451)
at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient$4.run(SOAPConnectorClient.java:380)
at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.reconnect(SOAPConnectorClient.java:365)
... 72 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had problems getting the Websphere Deploy Plugin running on a 'localhost' install of WAS7 with a Deployment Manager and a single Application Server node.  The cell default certificate needs to go into the Dmgr Truststore. Here's a summary of what what worked for me:

## 1A - Obtain the Websphere Cell Wide Certificate

https://localhost.localdomain:9043/ibm/console/login.do?action=secure

```
View Page Info (Right-Click) > Security > View Certificate
  Details Tab  -  Hit (Export...)
    save to /tmp/was-cell-certificate
```

## 1B - Obtain the Websphere Cell Wide Cert. in a more defined way]

```
WAS Console > Security > SSL Cert & key management
 Related Items : Key Stores and Certificates
   Clink blue link: Cell Default Keystore
    Additional Properties : Personal Certificates
     Checkbox for (default) alias
     Click Extract
     Send to /tmp/was-cell-certificate
     (OK)
```

## Import the Certificate into the Deployment Manager Truststore

```
[root@localhost etc]# cd /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/Dmgr01/etc
[root@localhost etc]# keytool -importcert -keystore DummyClientTrustFile.jks -alias myserver -file /tmp/was-cell-certificate -storepass WebAS
```

Comment: With the latest release v1.5.6 of the websphere deployer plugin, you can "Trust SSL Certificates". It's less likely that you need this level of security on a internal network, but if you're extra adventurous, feel free to use the Truststore, Keystore route... As @Jim Doyle stated, if you have a deployment manager (i.e. WAS ND), point the plugin to it, otherwise point to the admin console.

Answer (score 3):

Have you copied following jar files from your WebSphere:
- com.ibm.ws.admin.client_x.y.z.jar
- com.ibm.ws.orb_x.y.z.jar ?

If not, copy the files in your plugin's WEB-INF/lib folder and restart Jenkins.

Check if your CONNECTOR_PORT in WebSphere matches with the value you set in your Jenkins job.

I recommend that you copy DummyClientKeyFile.jks and DummyClientTrustFile.jks from Websphere installation to your Jenkins machine in some directory (for example, /etc/jenkins).

Configure the stores' paths (with /etc/jenkins folder) in the stores' file path fields (the picture you posted in question).

Try Googling the password for these stores, and set it password fields (the picture you posted in question).

Try deploy after these changes.

Works for me, but deployment of a  large WAR file (about 40MB) crashes the WebSphere sometimes.

Smaller WARs work OK.

Answer (score 0):

Import the Server Certificate to DummyClientTrustFile.jks.